# Chamar activity depois que a thread for executada

Tags: java, android

Tenho um app que faz o login de um professor em um webservice e logo apos fazer o login ele insere o usuário no banco do android. Caso resultado seja diferente de null, quero que chame a activity menu. Porem minha aplicação esta fechando.
Segue o codigo.

```
public class Login extends Activity {

ProfessorWS professorWS = new ProfessorWS();
Professor professor = new Professor();
ProfessorDAO professorDAO = new ProfessorDAO(this);
private EditText edUsuario, edSenha;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Menu.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    edUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edUsuario);
    edSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edSenha);

}

public void btEntrarOnClick (View view){


    String msg = getString(R.string.dlg_msg);
    String titulo = getString(R.string.dlg_titulo);

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, msg);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("user", edUsuario.getText().toString());
                params.put("senha", edSenha.getText().toString());

                professor = professorWS.buscarProfessor(params);
                professorDAO.insereProfessor(professor);

               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (professor.getCodProfessor() != null){ //
                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Código pro: " + professor.getCodProfessor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();


                        }else{
                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Código professor nao encotrado " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }).start();


}
```

Comment: normalmente fecha assim por que deu algum erro, via de regra alguma exeção que nao foi pega, verifica o logcat, provavelmente vai tem um stacktrace la

Comment: MInha duvida é se pode chamar a outra activity dentro ddo runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

Comment: Mas ja tentou fazer isso? Deu algum erro? Ate onde sei o `run()` já roda dentro da sua thead "principal", entao deve funcionar.

Comment: ja sim, deu o seguinte erro

Comment: ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivit

Comment: ProgressDialog.show funciona? Eu sempre uso o método show da varíavel dialog. Verifica se assim funciona. Talvez precise também colocar o show dentro de uma thread separada. Aí você usa o runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você fazer dessa forma abaixo:

```
if (professor.getCodProfessor() != null){ 
     Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Menu.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}else{
     Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Código professor nao encotrado ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

E não se esqueça de registrar a Activity la no seu manifest.

```
<activity
     android:name=".Menu"
     android:label="@string/menu_title">
</activity>
```